# Adding exception range to IDA

Tags: ida, unpacking, exception

I encountered a problem while trying to debug an application that raises an exception to stop the debugger.

How can I add an exception range, such as (00000000 - FFFFFFFF), in IDA as in Olly ?

Answer (score 3):

As I know you can handle exceptions from Debugger->Debugger Options and you can add or edit exceptions there, but there's no such option in IDA, in protected programs there are a lot anti debug tricks, you can use IDAStealth or such plugins to hide debugger sometimes these methods are the reason to exceptions

Comment: It's easy to add one exception at a time. But, I want to add a range to ignore all raised exceptions. Is there a way to do so ?


I use ScyllaHide for hiding. However, it's not enough !

Comment: Try IDA_NOEH environment variable: If set, disable IDA's own exception handler and let all possible crashes
to be handled by the OS or active debugger. It is useful if you're debugging
a crash in a plugin or processor module. P.S: I'm not sure if it can help you

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't work !

This is a sample :
https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.141
Try to run the file "UnPackMe_Fusion4.0.00.c.exe" in IDA.